# Check admin authorization with AuthorizeView from AuthenticationStateProvider

Tags: c#, razor, blazor-webassembly

I'm using the `AuthenticationStateProvider` in my Blazor WASM project and I figured out how to show content for logged in users but how can I show content for users who are logged in AND have admin privileges? My backend API send the "Admin" claim in the JWT token but I can't figure out how to read it using the `AuthorizeView` component.

```
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <MudButton OnClick="Logout">Logout</MudButton>
    </Authorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify roles in the AuthorizeView component as parameters:

```
<AuthorizeView Roles="Admin">
    <Authorized>
        <MudButton OnClick="Logout">Logout</MudButton>
    </Authorized> 
</AuthorizeView>
```

Documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#role-based-and-policy-based-authorization